# Adding an index to mongo does not improve query performance

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm building an app that relays on MongoDB 3.4

I have created few indexes which work fine, though, when I have tried to run a find action, the action runs forever, I then created a compound Index that contains the two fields I run my find query on but still no change, this is what I have tried so far:

```
IMongoCollection<FlightPair> FlightsPair = _db.GetCollection<FlightPair>("Flights");
FlightsPair.Indexes.CreateOne(Builders<FlightPair>.IndexKeys.Ascending(_ => _.Source.ExternalId).Ascending(_ => _.Source.HashCode));

public async Task<FlightPair> GetFlightByHashCodeAndId(string hashCode,string id)
{
    return await FlightsPair.Find(x => x.Source.HashCode == hashCode && x.Source.ExternalId == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

I have also tried this :

```
    var uniqueIdIndex = new CreateIndexOptions();
    uniqueIdIndex.Unique = false;
    uniqueIdIndex.Sparse = true;
    FlightsPair.Indexes.CreateOne(Builders<FlightPair>.IndexKeys.Ascending(_ => _.Source.ExternalId).Ascending(_ => _.Source.HashCode), uniqueIdIndex);
```

But no luck -
GetFlightByHashCodeAndId never ends, what am i missing?

Comment: Perhaps that's as optimised as you can make it. I'm guessing your mongo instance is very large?

Comment: try firing the query from shell along with `.explain()` and see if the index is being used or not.

Comment: not really, 250 documents, I have another index on x.Source.HashCode which works fine so i'm not sure what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem, it was with the async task, nothing related to mongo, thanks for your replies!